# Blocking " Unknown database" message when connecting a new MYSQL database in Java

Tags: java, mysql

I am making an FXML application with intelliJ and MYSQL in Java 11 that allows the user to create a database that has a name of their own choosing. The application:

1. recognises that the database doesn't yet exist
2. creates the database via a connect string that uses URL without a specfic DB name
3. connects to the new database and executes an sql.txt file thereby creating all the required tables.

This approach works save for the fact that when the final statement of the code below executes an automated alert pops up with:

"Cannot connect to database. Please close the program, check the driver is available and that the connection details are correct and then try logging on again".

It does this even though the new database with all required tables has been created and connected to.

Question: Is there anyway to disable this auto-generated message?

```
protected void execute() throws Exception {
        // Connect using URL without DBNAME:This is a re-assignment of inherited value

        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

        // Create database at user request:
        String sql = "CREATE DATABASE " + this.newDBName;
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        StringBuilder sqlText = new StringBuilder();
        File file = new File(this.getClass().getResource("createSQLScript.txt").toURI());

            /*
            Read in the Sql statement text file resource to create tables
            using try-with resources and automatic resource closure.*/
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sqlText.append(line);
            }
        }
        // Set connection object to allow multiple queries in createSQLScript.txt
        // A re-assignment of inherited value
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL + this.newDBName + "?allowMultiQueries=true", USER, PASS);
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sqlText.toString());
        stmt.executeUpdate(sqlText.toString());


    }
```

PS: DB_URL is - jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/

Answer (score 0):

This could be related to the fact that you created database in one connection and started accessing it in another connection without closing the previous one.

`Connection` and `PreparedStatement` are closable resources. You should always close them with `try-finally` or `try-with-resources` pattern, e.g.:

```java
try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS)) {
    try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        // execute stmt...
        // populate database...
    }
}
try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
        DB_URL + this.newDBName + "?allowMultiQueries=true", USER, PASS) {
    // access newly created database...
}
```

Comment: Thanks fo your reply. The exception thrown is : java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet is from UPDATE. No Data" . This seems to suggest that JDBC doesn't like executing scripts that create tables rather than queries that operate on data within them. Though I would like to avoid throwing an error in the first place I might have to handle the error gracefully whilst I work out a way to eliminate it altogether. I don't think the source of the error is open connection. I've refactored the code to close resources and the original problem is still occurring..

Comment: @Kammo3 `ResultSet is from UPDATE. No Data` means that you try to execute an SQL statement with `executeUpdate`, but the statement is not actually an `UPDATE` statement. If your `createSQLScript.txt` file contains DML statements (`CREATE TABLE` etc.), then you should run it with `stmt.execute()` instead. Also, if your file contains multiple statements, you won't be able to execute it with a single `stmt.execute()` call, they have to be executed separately.